# Excel VBA Open Workbooks without duplicating it

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of filenames in one of my workbook. I was wondering if anyone knows how to open the file when the name is not in that list. For example, the list contains names for file “ab”, “bc”, “cd” & “de”. File “ac”, “bd” & “eg” are not in the list, and I only want to open that files so there is no duplication. I know I can just remove the duplication, but it’s time consuming to open files that already exist in the list. I’m new with VBA and I did some research about this topic, but found nothing. I really appreciate anyone that can help me. Thank you!

So here is what I came up so far:

```
Sub Test1()

Dim File As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbList As Workbook
Dim filesRange As Range
Dim f As Range
Dim fileName As String
Dim Average As Double
Dim StdDev As Double
Dim OpenNum As Double
Dim Min As Double
Dim Max As Double
Dim wbDestination As Workbook

Const wbPath As String = "C:\Users\10 stop.xlsx"
Const pathToFiles As String = "C:\Users\J\"

File = Dir(pathToFiles, vbDirectory)

Set wbList = Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
Set filesRange = wbList.Sheets("18x17 - 10 mil stop").Range("A:A")

Do While Len(File) > 0
    Set f = filesRange.Find(What:=f, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If f Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(pathToFiles & File)

        fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        Worksheets(1).Select
        Average = Range("B15")
        Worksheets(1).Select
        StdDev = Range("B16")
        Worksheets(1).Select
        OpenNum = Range("B13")
        Worksheets(1).Select
        Min = Range("B17")
        Worksheets(1).Select
        Max = Range("B18")

        Set wbDestination = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\10 stop.xlsx")
        Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Select
        Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("a1").Select
        RowCount = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        With Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("a1")
        .Offset(RowCount, 0) = fileName
        .Offset(RowCount, 1) = Average
        .Offset(RowCount, 2) = StdDev
        .Offset(RowCount, 3) = OpenNum
        .Offset(RowCount, 4) = Min
        .Offset(RowCount, 5) = Max
        End With
    End If
    File = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

I got Runtime-error '5': Invalid Procedure Call or Argument on

```
Set f = filesRange.Find(What:=f, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
```

For the files that I want to open and read, I would like to use wildcard "*-10_*.csv" 
I tried many different ways, but all of them gave me blank sheets as result.
I used the 'RecursiveDir' previously, but it's slow and open every files over and over again when I try to update my data.
This is so frustrating :(
Please help!

Comment: I am a little confused, you do or do not want to open files "ac", "bd" and "eg"?  Also how are these file names generated, also is this list manually maintained?

Comment: Yes, I want to open files "ac" "bd" & "eg". Right now, I have a program that open all the files in the designated directory (ex: C://hello). My problem is that when I run the program, it will open all the files in that directory, even the one that already exist in the workbook. The file names are serial numbers of the products, and I can’t predict what the next one would be.  The list is updated only when there is new serial numbers available.

Comment: Use `Dir()` to loop through all the files in the folder: check the filenames against your list and only open those which are not found in the list.

Comment: I would have thought a Folders object that gives you a collection of files (effectively an array of file names) would be better than `Dir()`.

Comment: @TimWilliams Could you show me how to do it? I have no slight idea how to do it.

Comment: @TonyDallimore - I would only use FSO if `Dir()` wasn't up to the job.  Dir() is cross-platform (works on macs) and I believe it's faster than FSO when iterating over folders/files.

Comment: @TimWilliams I got it loop through the files in the folder, but how can I check the list of filenames in the worksheet? The worksheet that contain all the names are in different folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added sub-folder searching. Compiled but not tested.

```
Sub Test1()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbList As Workbook
Dim filesRange As Range
Dim f As Range
Dim wbDestination As Workbook
Dim rw As Range
Dim allFiles As New Collection, File, fName

Const wbPath As String = "C:\Users\10 stop.xlsx"
Const pathToFiles As String = "C:\Users\J\"

    Set wbList = Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
    Set filesRange = wbList.Sheets("18x17 - 10 mil stop").Range("A:A")

    GetFiles pathToFiles, "*-10_.csv", True, allFiles

    For Each File In allFiles

        fName = FileNameOnly(File)

        Set f = filesRange.Find(What:=fName, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)

        If f Is Nothing Then

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(File)

            '***need to specify sheet name below...
            Set rw = wbList.Sheets("sheetname").Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
                       .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow

            rw.Cells(1).Value = fName 'or `File` if you want the full path
            With wb.Sheets(1)
                rw.Cells(2).Value = .Range("B15").Value 'avg
                rw.Cells(3).Value = .Range("B16").Value 'stdev
                rw.Cells(4).Value = .Range("B13").Value 'opennum
                rw.Cells(5).Value = .Range("B17").Value 'min
                rw.Cells(6).Value = .Range("B18").Value 'max
            End With
            wb.Close False 'don't save

        End If
    Next File

End Sub

'given a path, return only the filename
Function FileNameOnly(sPath)
Dim arr
    arr = Split(sPath, "\")
    FileNameOnly = arr(UBound(arr))
End Function




Sub GetFiles(StartFolder As String, Pattern As String, _
             DoSubfolders As Boolean, ByRef colFiles As Collection)

    Dim f As String, sf As String, subF As New Collection, s

    If Right(StartFolder, 1) <> "\" Then StartFolder = StartFolder & "\"

    f = Dir(StartFolder & Pattern)
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        colFiles.Add StartFolder & f
        f = Dir()
    Loop

    sf = Dir(StartFolder, vbDirectory)
    Do While Len(sf) > 0
        If sf <> "." And sf <> ".." Then
            If (GetAttr(StartFolder & sf) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
                    subF.Add StartFolder & sf
            End If
        End If
        sf = Dir()
    Loop

    For Each s In subF
        GetFiles CStr(s), Pattern, True, colFiles
    Next s

End Sub
```

Comment: Assume that the workbook is not open yet, can I do it like this: 

    Set filesRange = Workbooks.Open("C:\folder1\myFiles\files.xlsx")
    Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Select
    Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A:A").Select

I can't get anything pass that. It just open the workbook and do nothing. As trial, I put MsgBox "found" inside the if statement, but nothing is shown.

Comment: I got a run-time error '1004' on the `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(pathToFiles & File)`. It show that C:\Users\J\J.xlsx could not be found. Why is it showing file "J.xlsx"? If I only want to open .csv file, where should I set it? I tried putting it here and there, but nothing works.

Comment: Sorry for being so dumb, but I still can't get it to work properly. It open the **10 stop.xlsx** but after that, nothing is copied over.  In my understanding, it open the **10 stop.xlsx** and then it read range (A:A). After that it goes to the directory and find the file that match in range (A:A), right?  If the files not match with the one in range (A:A), it should copy the data from cell b15 ,b16 ,b13, b17, b18 and paste the data to the cells 1-6 in the **10 stop.xlsx** file. Am I missing something here? If not, why it does nothing other than open the **10 stop.xlsx** file? Btw, thank you!

Comment: Forgot to mention, if the file is inside a sub-sub-folder, will that cause the problem? For example, in the "J" folder there is sub-folders and sub-sub-folder. In that sub-sub-folder is where the csv.file is located.

Comment: Well that changes things! The code doesn't search sub-folders.  I can edit later to fix that.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm getting frustrated cause it keep opening the file, but the data never got updated.